# Topic and queue with the same name, classcastexception

Tags: apache, jms, activemq-classic

my question is, using ActiveMQ can we have a topic and queue with the same name for jndi?.

I have both defined with the same name, and when I try to create a queue with lookup I´m receiving this exception.

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic cannot be cast to javax.jms.Queue
```

Comment: If you share a name, how do you think JNDI will pick the right object for you? They are not compatible.

Comment: Because one address is to create a Queue and the same one is used to create a Topic. Tibco for instance allow reuse the same address, but seems like ActiveMQ dont. But just want to be 100% sure

Comment: please ask a single question, you can edit the question if it has some problems, please delete duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

While you can actually have a topic and queue with the same name you cannot share a JNDI name between a topic and a queue. A JNDI name makes you lookup a single object (queue or topic).

So - make sure you have JNDI entries with unique names.

```
queue.MyQueue = samePhysicalName
topic.MyTopic = samePhysicalName
```

Although I think it's bad practice to share names, since it's harder to document, trouble shoot etc etc.

Comment: My problem is that in one environment we have tibco that use the jndi using two different files. One for queue and another for topics. So it´s possible create a topic or queue with same names since he is searching for topic file if you want a topic and queue file if you want a queue. But activeMQ use the same jndi.properties where I have topics and queues address